# getaddrinfo() with IPv6 not making sense

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, ipv6, getaddrinfo

I don't understand why `getaddrinfo` is not returning a valid IPv6 address.

On my system the code below is printing `22:B8:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00`, but I expected a `01` somewhere, since `localhost` should resolve to `::1`.

At the same time, `sa_data` is only 14 bytes, whereas IPv6 addresses are 16 bytes, so it seems that the last couple of bytes are always chopped off, and the function *can't* return an IPv6 address?

Can someone explain what's going on? How am I supposed to use this function with IPv6?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2TCPIP.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WSAStartup(0x0002, &wsadata);
    addrinfo addr_hints = { 0, PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP }, *addrs_out;
    getaddrinfo("localhost", "8888", &addr_hints, &addrs_out);
    fprintf(stderr,
        "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 0]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 1]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 2]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 3]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 4]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 5]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 6]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 7]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 8]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[ 9]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[10]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[11]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[12]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(addrs_out->ai_addr->sa_data[13]));
    freeaddrinfo(addrs_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First be sure to check the return value of `getaddrinfo()`. If it fails your addresses will be garbage.

Comment: @Jeff: I am in my actual code; that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sockaddr` struct definitions for reference:

```
struct sockaddr {
    ushort  sa_family;
    char    sa_data[14];
};


struct sockaddr_in6 {
    short   sin6_family;
    u_short sin6_port;
    u_long  sin6_flowinfo;
    struct  in6_addr sin6_addr;
    u_long  sin6_scope_id;
};
```

When `ai_family == AF_INET6` `ai_addr` actually points to a `struct sockaddr_in6`. The first few bytes you are printing are `sin6_port` and `sin6_flowinfo`. The IPv6 address comes after.

Edit to add:

You can use `ai_addr` directly with functions like `bind()` and `getnameinfo()`. You typically won't need to dig down into the struct definition details. For example, I would use `getnameinfo()` with `NI_NUMERICHOST` to get a printable address.

Comment: Aw man, I thought `sockaddr` was big enough to hold `sockaddr_in6` but it seems that's what `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` is for! That finally makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Side question, but do you happen to know if there is a place that lists the length of every single standard address family?

Comment: @Mehrdad Not that I know of. There are 40ish of of them and their own sockaddr definitions are scattered around various header files.

Answer (score 1):

> [sockaddr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) are not strictly interpreted to be pointers to a
>   sockaddr structure. The structure is interpreted differently in the
>   context of different address families.

so we need first check `sa_family` of [`sockaddr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) or `ai_family` from `addrinfo` (in this base it must be equal) and based on this need "reinterpret" pointer from [`sockaddr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) (this like `void*` pointer) to real structure. say use union for this:

```
addrinfo *addrs_out, *addr;

if (getaddrinfo("localhost", "8888", 0, &addrs_out) == NOERROR)
{
    addr = addrs_out;

    CHAR buf[256], *sz, srv[128];
    ULONG n;
    PUCHAR Byte;

    do 
    {
        union {
            sockaddr* ai_addr;
            SOCKADDR_IN* pa;
            SOCKADDR_IN6* pa6;
        };

        ai_addr = addr->ai_addr;

        if (addr->ai_family != ai_addr->sa_family)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        switch (addr->ai_family)
        {
        case AF_INET6:
            Byte = pa6->sin6_addr.u.Byte, n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(pa6->sin6_addr.u.Byte), sz = buf;
            do 
            {
                sz += sprintf(sz, "%02X:", *Byte++);
            } while (--n);

            sz[-1] = 0;
            DbgPrint("AF_INET6: %s\n", buf);
            break;

        case AF_INET:
            if (0 <= RtlIpv4AddressToStringExA(&pa->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, pa->sin_port, buf, &(n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf))))
            {
                DbgPrint("AF_INET: %s\n", buf);
            }
            break;
        }

        // alt print
        if (getnameinfo(ai_addr, (socklen_t)addr->ai_addrlen, buf, RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), srv, RTL_NUMBER_OF(srv), NI_NUMERICHOST ) == NOERROR)
        {
            DbgPrint("%s:%s\n", buf, srv);
        }

    } while (addr = addr->ai_next);

    freeaddrinfo(addrs_out);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile in `gcc`. I think it was for C++?

Comment: @davidhcefx - yes, it c++, some cl internals like `__debugbreak()`; but all this is cosmetich changes only. in what problem ?

Comment: No big problem. The problem is that in c it is not valid to access `union` members like that. So if it was for c++ only, it's better to add a note in case confused some readers.

Comment: @davidhcefx yes, [c++](https://godbolt.org/z/94jnKhsYW) vs  [c](https://godbolt.org/z/5GT9nnhEd). in *c* possible use `union {..} u;` and `u.ai_addr`, `u.pa`, `u.pa6` .. or use reinterpret cast